# PyGTK Spacing in an HBox

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm new to GTK, I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish something like this:

```
+---+------+---+
|   |      |   |
|   |      |   |
|   |      |   |
|   |      |   |
|   |      |   |
|   |      |   |
+---+------+---+
```

I want this done in an HBox. How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose the drawings you give are "frames" ? Do the user have to see them ? Do you want a specific width ? Your answers will help me write a good sample for you.

Comment: Well, not exactly a specific width, more like the left and the right has the same width, and the center has a bigger width (setting a specifc width would be fine, though)

Answer (score 0):

It is done with "packing".

I always keep the class reference under my pillow : http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-class-reference.html

Samples in the good tutorial found here :
http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-DetailsOfBoxes.html

And finally, this shows up something like your drawing :

```
import gtk as g

win = g.Window ()
win.set_default_size(600, 400)
win.set_position(g.WIN_POS_CENTER)
win.connect ('delete_event', g.main_quit)
hBox = g.HBox()
win.add (hBox)
f1 = g.Frame()
f2 = g.Frame()
f3 = g.Frame()
hBox.pack_start(f1)
hBox.pack_start(f2)
hBox.pack_start(f3)
win.show_all ()

g.main ()
```

Have fun ! (and I hope my answer is helpful)

Comment: That doesn't help me though.. the packing will automatically expand the frames if there are content, but I want the center frame to always be larger and the side ones to be always identical

Comment: Well, use the available parameters in both pack-start and pack-end methods and you're gone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pack_start() and pack_end()

The function has a few parameters you can send to it that give you the desired effect

If you use Louis' example:

```
hBox.pack_start(f1, expand =False, fill=False)
hBox.pack_start( f2, expand=True, fill=True, padding=50)
hBox.pack_end(f3, expand=False, fill=False)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That would just give it a padding, it doesn't actually extend the box (and its content). Also the False on the fill would cram my other boxes...